# Which fork version is the py-cryptonight hash library using?

Tags: mining-theory

I was wondering what version the [py-cryptonight](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight) library is using. For example, is it CryptoNight lite v2, CryptoNight v8, CryptoNight heavy?

Answer (score 1):

As of right [now](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight/tree/25a131576da0a267c4ae42dcfb14f592886f01a4), it's using the latest version of CryptoNight (CNv2, as used in Monero hard-fork v9). CryptoNight *lite* is not used by Monero, neither is *heavy*. CN *lite* first appeared in Aeon IIRC and is (as is *heavy*) a different algorithm altogether.

Comment: What? wait... i thought monero was using cnV9, now?

Comment: There are lots of different "versions" when talking about Monero. Hard-fork version (currently v9), CryptoNight variant (currently v2), tx version etc etc.